# Jekyll remove Github user name and repo name from generated URLs

Tags: github, url, jekyll, github-actions

I am trying to deloy a Jekyll site using FTP to a web server using Github actions. Everytime I deploy it all of the URLs generated have "/PAGES/GITHUB-USERNAME/REPO-NAME/" injected in the middle of them and look like the following:

```
https://domain.tld/PAGES/GITHUB-USERNAME/REPO-NAME/assets/css/main.css
```

This is consequently breaking all of the CSS, Javascript and links between pages. All of the files generated are still in the correct places.

When I run the site locally, all of the links work as expected and look like the following:

```
http://127.0.0.1:4000/assets/css/main.css
```

Is there a way that I can get the URLs to look like:

```
https://domain.tld/assets/css/main.css
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Huzzah! Managed to fix it.

In '_config.yml' you must specify a FQDN with the protocol as "url:" and for baseurl just leave empty since no baseurl is required.

I don't know if both of these are required because I added them at the same time.

```
url: 'https://sub.domain.tld'
baseurl: ''
```